# Strategy for rainfire-like moves

Tags: marvel-vs-capcom-infinite

Watching a gameplay video of Hawkeye in Marvel vs Capcom Infinite, I noticed that he has a move where he shoots an arrow to the sky just to make it fall like a "rain fire", hitting the enemy. I also noticed that this repeats in other Marvel vs Capcom games, like with Taskmaster.

What is the strategy in using such move, since it is not aimed at the enemy directly?